# structure definitions

Tags: scheme, racket

I am asked to create a structure definition for every animal that is kept in a zoo. For each animal, they store its name, age, breakfast hour, dinner hour, and species.

```
 (define-struct animal (name species age breakfast-hour dinner-hour))
```

Now, each zoo attendant has a name and is assigned to watch over exactly three different animals in the zoo.

Would it be something like this?

```
(define attendant(make-attendant "David" "Leo" '))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `attendant` structure with the needed fields. Name, age, whatever - and with three extra fields, one for each assigned animal, and pass the three animals at the moment of creating the attendant.